# Python random numbers

Tags: python, random, attributeerror

I can't understand the problem in python. I have such code:

```
class Rain:
    def __init__(self):
       self.x = random.randint(0, Core.Utils.ScreenResolutionX)
       print type(Core.Utils.ScreenResolutionX) # prints int
       print Core.Utils.ScreenResolutionX # print 1152
```

Error:

```
    self.x = random.randint(0, Core.Utils.ScreenResolutionX)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 241, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 213, in randrange
    if width >= maxwidth:
AttributeError: 'Rain' object has no attribute 'getType'
```

Comment: You should tell us how do you invoke your code...

Comment: @ssegvic Main application code is written in c++. I invoke this code using boost.python in my cpp-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL` is being returned to Python in one of your methods erroneously. *Always* make sure to incref and return `PyNone` to Python if no exception needs to be raised.

Comment: So the issue isn't related to random module? As I show in example, I print my exported variable and it shows well.